# MySQL Row more appear with multiple row same result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have a query with a count with some group by, and I want to get the greater count. I can do with an order by and limit 1, but I have multiple results with the same count and then does not work for me.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: 5.6. But I want to know too in H2 database.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what your query looks like.

Answer (score 0):

With MySql 8+, you can use [CTE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/) to get the maximum count, and then retrieve all records with a count equal to the maximum count.

However, since CTE is not available in MySql 5.6, you'd need to use a sub-query to get the maximum count, and then write the main query which compares the count of each record to the maximum count retrieved in the subquery.

Here is a query I wrote. Maybe it's not the most efficient solution, but it gets the desired result.

```
SELECT 
    group_id, COUNT(record_id) c 
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING c IN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(sub_query.c)
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            group_id, COUNT(record_id) c
        FROM
            table_name
        GROUP BY group_id) AS sub_query
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to do this using window functions, you can do:

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(*) as cnt 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM table_name
              GROUP BY group_id
              ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
              LIMIT 1
             ) ;
```